# How do I return a list with newly added objects from a method (Beginner) C#

Tags: c#, list, object, methods, return

I am having trouble returning a list from a method called "omvandlaBetyg" which translates to "convert grades". I have added a total of 5 'char' to my list. I wish to return the list from the method.

With many attempts I have not been able to solve this issue.
I am sorry for having set the names of the lists/variables to another language.

If it is too difficult to try and find a solution for my issue then I will translate it as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ämnen = { "Matematik", "Svenska", "Engelska", "Historia", "Fysik" };
        int[] poäng = new int[5];
        List<char> betyg = new List<char>(); // This is the list that is currently empty

        Program.LäsPoäng(poäng);

        Program.omvandlaBetyg(poäng, betyg);

        Program.skrivUtBetyg(betyg, ämnen);

    }
    static int LäsPoäng(int[] poäng)
    {
        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för matematik:");
        int matPoäng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för svenska:");
        int svePoäng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för engelska:");
        int engPoäng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för historia:");
        int hisPoäng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för fysik:");
        int fysPoäng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        poäng[0] = matPoäng;
        poäng[1] = svePoäng;
        poäng[2] = engPoäng;
        poäng[3] = hisPoäng;
        poäng[4] = fysPoäng;

        return poäng[4];
    }
    static char omvandlaBetyg(int[] poäng, List <char> betyg)
    {

        foreach (int i in poäng)
        {
            if (i < 50)
            {
                betyg.Add('F');
            }
            else if (i >= 50 && i < 60)
            {
                betyg.Add('E');
            }
            else if (i > 60 && i < 75)
            {
                betyg.Add('D');
            }
            else if (i > 75 && i < 90)
            {
                betyg.Add('C');
            }
            else if (i > 90 && i < 100)
            {
                betyg.Add('B');
            }
            else if (i == 100)
            {
                betyg.Add('A');
            }
        }
        return betyg; // This is the list that has been updated with newly added char's
                      // that i wish to return from this method
    }
    static void skrivUtBetyg(List<char> betyg, string[] ämnen)
    {
        foreach (char item in betyg)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Betyg i : " + item );
        }
    }
    static void Statistik()
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Change your method to: `static List<char> omvandlaBetyg(int[] poäng, List<char> betyg)`

Comment: Or like this : `static void omvandlaBetyg(int[] poäng, out List<char> betyg)` but you have to instantiate the generic list in your method `betyg = new List<char>();` before the loop, and you also have to remove the `return` line as the `out` parameter will do the job instead. If you decide to keep the `return` line in your code, then you will have to adjust to return type of the method accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the return type of the method `omvandlaBetyg` from `char` to `List<char>`

Here I fixed your code:

```
static List<char> omvandlaBetyg(int[] poäng, List <char> betyg)
{
    foreach (int i in poäng)
    {
        if (i < 50)
        {
            betyg.Add('F');
        }
        else if (i >= 50 && i < 60)
        {
            betyg.Add('E');
        }
        else if (i > 60 && i < 75)
        {
            betyg.Add('D');
        }
        else if (i > 75 && i < 90)
        {
            betyg.Add('C');
        }
        else if (i > 90 && i < 100)
        {
            betyg.Add('B');
        }
        else if (i == 100)
        {
            betyg.Add('A');
        }
    }
    return betyg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to learn C#, but there are a few odd things in your code; here's what it could look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ämnen = new string[] { "Matematik", "Svenska", "Engelska", "Historia", "Fysik" };

    // No need to create your lists/arrays here and pass them to these methods
    // as they can return them directly

    var poäng = LäsPoäng(ämnen);
    var betyg = OmvandlaBetyg(poäng);
    SkrivUtBetyg(betyg);
}

// The purpose of that method is to query grades and return them
static List<int> LäsPoäng(string[] ämnen)
{
    // Create your list here, and return it when you've asked all grades
    var poäng = new List<int>();

    // Redundant code, you've got a list of subjects so you might as well use them
    // This means you could add new subjects without changing this method
    foreach (var str in ämnen)
    {
        Console.Write($"Ange totalpoäng för {str.ToLower()}:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    return poäng;
}

// The purpose of that method is to convert integer grades to A-F
// Method name should use camel case
static List<char> OmvandlaBetyg(List<int> poäng)
{
    // Create your list here, and return it when you've converted all grades
    var betyg = new List<char>();

    foreach (int i in poäng)
    {
        if (i < 50)
            betyg.Add('F');
        else if (i < 60) // No need to check lower bound, previous "if" takes care of it
            betyg.Add('E');
        else if (i < 75)
            betyg.Add('D');
        else if (i < 90)
            betyg.Add('C');
        else if (i < 100)
            betyg.Add('B');
        else
            betyg.Add('A');
    }

    return betyg;
}

// Camel case
static void SkrivUtBetyg(List<char> betyg)
{
    foreach (char item in betyg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Betyg i : {item}");
    }
}
```

It could still be improved and is by no means perfect, but hopefully it will give you some pointers.